# Current Tag included under Related Tags

Tags: bug, tags, top-users, related-tags

Initially only for the "Top Users" page of a tag, it now seems to also be true for other pages such as "hot", "new", "synonyms".

Confirmed for multiple sites and tags.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Patrick Repro'd on a page with synonyms https://i.stack.imgur.com/Venwr.png

Comment: Interesting that the reference counters are sometimes different though. Suggests they may be pulling from separate sources.

Comment: More than an year and still not fixed :( Still observable on the "Top Users" page of many sites. Here's an example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/faq-proposed/topusers

Comment: It can actually be observed in all 4 tabs, also `hot` ([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/errors/hot)) and `new` ([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/errors/hot)), both for tags with and tags without synonyms.

Comment: This is also the case for the Tag Synonyms page.

Comment: This is still a thing :)

Comment: So why _are_ tags related to themselves?